Use one regex to extract information from two patterns
I would like to simplify below regex logic with one regex statement. Then it's easier to understand the logic.
import re

content = """
[    1.765989] initcall init_module.cfi_jt+0x0/0x8 [altmode_glink] returned 0 after 379 usecs
[    0.001873] initcall selinux_init+0x0/0x1f8 returned 0 after 85 usecs
"""

for line in content.split("\n"):
    m = re.search("\[\s+(?P<ts>[\d.]+)\] initcall init_module.*\[(?P<func>[^ ]+)\] returned (?P<ret>[\d-]+) after (?P<val>[\d-]+) usecs",line)
    if m:
        ts = m['ts']
        func = m['func']
        ret = m['ret']
        val = m['val']
        print(ts,func,ret,val)
    else:
        m = re.search("\[\s+(?P<ts>[\d.]+)\] initcall (?P<func>[^ ]+)\+.*? returned (?P<ret>[\d-]+) after (?P<val>[\d-]+) usecs",line)
        if m:
            ts = m['ts']
            func = m['func']
            ret = m['ret']
            val = m['val']
            print(ts,func,ret,val)

Current output is good:
1.765989 altmode_glink 0 379
0.001873 selinux_init 0 85


r"\[\s+(?P<ts>[\d.]+)\] initcall.+(\[)?\b(?P<func>[^][\s+]+)(?(2)]|\+.*?) returned (?P<ret>[\d-]+) after (?P<val>[\d-]+) usecs"

The tricky part is apparently how you identify a function name, which can be be matched by non-left-bracket characters followed by either a right bracket or a plus sign followed by non-spaces:
for ts, func, ret, val in re.findall(
        r'\[\s*([\d.]+)] initcall .*?([^[]+)(?:]|\+\S+) '
        r'returned (\d+) after (\d+) usecs', content):
    print(ts, func, ret, val)

This outputs:
1.765989 altmode_glink 0 379
0.001873 selinux_init 0 85

Demo here

Another version, using single pattern (regex101 link):
import re

content = """
[    1.765989] initcall init_module.cfi_jt+0x0/0x8 [altmode_glink] returned 0 after 379 usecs
[    0.001873] initcall selinux_init+0x0/0x1f8 returned 0 after 85 usecs
"""

pattern = r"(?P<ts>[\d.]+).*(?P<func>(?<= )\S+(?=\+)|(?<=\[)[^\]]+).*?returned (?P<ret>\d+) after (?P<val>\d+)"

for m in re.finditer(pattern, content):
    print(m["ts"])
    print(m["func"])
    print(m["ret"])
    print(m["val"])
    print()

Prints:
1.765989
altmode_glink
0
379

0.001873
selinux_init
0
85

